# java html content with multiple single and double quotation marks

Tags: java, html, string, quotations, quotation-marks

- Hello All its simple question but am not able to answer.
- i have written java code for html content String.
- my goal is: **when Click Here open yahoo.com & google.com pages**
- am able to open html and click on ***Click Here*** tag i am open only **yahoo.com page** and **not able to open google.com page**
- am facing the issues with **" "** and **' '** symbols in right places..
- Code is

  ```
  String content;
  content = "<html><head>....."
  +"<a href='http://yahoo.com' "
  + "onclick=\"window.open('http://google.com'); \">"
  + "Click Here</a>"
  ....
  +"</body>"
  +"</html>"
  ```

Comment: Is the semicolon missing in your actual code? What kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: @CartesianTheater, thank you for replay, this String content added to `email.setHtml(content)`, in email click on ClickHere am not able open google.com, am able to open yahoo.com ..

Comment: You mention this is going into an email.  Email clients are a more restrictive environment for HTML content, to help protect the users from malicious code.  Perhaps the email client is choosing to ignore the onclick or window.open javascript calls.

Comment: @DanArmstrong, thank you Dan, please can you **suggest that the how to call two href for single text in email html content..**

Comment: Kinda thinking outside the box a bit.  But you could link to a page on a server that does the heavy lifting with a small script.  The mail client opens a single URL to this script in the browser, then the browser does the "window.open" and then "window.location.href" in the script.  More complicated and I left out a bunch of details, but just presenting the idea of a server component to bridge the gap.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
public class Test{

 public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    String content;
    content = "<html><head>"
    +"<a href='http://yahoo.com'"
    + "onclick=\"window.open('http://google.com'); \">"
    + "Click Here</a>"
    +"</body>"
    +"</html>";
    System.out.println(content);
 }
```

}

and pasted the resulting string into a blank html file, opened it in a browser, and saw that it worked as I expected (a link to Yahoo that opens both Yahoo and Google.).

Comment: thank you for replay, this String content added to `email.setHtml(content)`, i got email with this html body, but in email click on ClickHere, am not able open google.com, am able to open yahoo.com ..